# Clicking a hyperlink in Excel to set an auto filter on a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have a detailed product order worksheet example table 2. and a summary worksheet supplier name and total value example Table 2.
I want to know is it possible when I click the hyperlink details will filter my detailed product order sheet under this supplier all order example table 3.
If anyone can do this for me it will be helpful for me

Table 1
[image: Table 1]

Table 2
[image: Table 2]

Table 3
[image: Table 3]

Comment: Please also describe what table 1 is for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event to detect when a hyperlink has been pressed.  A hyperlink to a location within the document will have a `SubAddress`, and the text that you clicked on will be the `TextToDisplay`.

The following code will detect when you click a hyperlink to a worksheet and - if that worksheet has an autofilter - will filter the first column of the AutoFilter for the text that you clicked on.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim wsToFilter As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo SubErr
    If Right(Target.SubAddress, 3) = "!A1" Then 'Hyperlink is to a worksheet within this document
        Set wsToFilter = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Replace(Target.SubAddress, "!A1", ""))
        If wsToFilter.AutoFilterMode Then 'Hyperlink has an AutoFilter
            wsToFilter.AutoFilter.ShowAllData 'Remove existing filters
            wsToFilter.AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter 1, Target.TextToDisplay 'Filter the First column for the text of the hyperlink
        End If
        Set wsToFilter = Nothing
    End If
SubErr:
End Sub
```

Comment: this is my file can you check what is the actual problem.

Comment: Comparing my explanation and the comments in my code against your screenshots:  This will try to filter all of your sheets for  "Details".  You need to change `Target.TextToDisplay` to something like `Target.Range.EntireRow.Cells(1,1).Value` so that it filters for the value in Column A of the row with the Hyperlink you clicked

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Worksheet.FollowHyperlink Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.followhyperlink) to filter the desired data.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    MsgBox Cells(Target.Parent.Row, "A") 'returns the value of column A of the clicked link
    'do your filter stuff here …
End Sub
```